# How to change the Session cookie value in Cakephp

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, session-cookies

In my Cakephp application, i have a session cookie with the name 'my_cookie' and it contains some random value 'QSD5111AS552DNJK'.

I observed that the value is same for the cookie (Before login and After login also). If i want to change the cookie value after login, what are the steps i have to follow. 
And my code in core.php file

```
Configure::write('Session', array(

    'defaults' => 'php',

    'cookie' => 'my_cookie',

    'timeout' => 4000 

));
```

Please help me in this issue for getting more clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess what you want to do is prevent session fixation, in that case it should be noted that CakePHP already does this for you out of the box. When using the [**authentication component**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html), the session is being renewed before the authenticated user data is being written to it, and after the user data is being deleted on logout.

See

- **[Source > AuthComponent::login()](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.6.8/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php#L603)**
- **[Source > AuthComponent::logout()](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.6.8/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php#L631)**

For the sake of completeness, you can always renew the session manually, either via the session component in case you are in a controller

```
$this->Session->renew();
```

or by using the `CakeSession` class directly

```
App::uses('CakeSession', 'Model/Datasource');
CakeSession::renew();
```

Comment: This `renew()` is especially useful when you want to reset the session timeout after each request - just need to add it in `beforeFilter()`, otherwise the default cake behavior is to expire the session after a set timeout after authentication as defined in `Session.timeout`. Both have their advantages, depending on your business needs.